# A small  bag for a large pro camera body with a small lens?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-bag, equipment-protection, transport

The Canon 5D Mark 2 with the 50mm Canon 1.4 USM lens has a pretty odd shape.

It is really short and really wide.

As it turns out, from my visit to two photography stores yesterday, not too many companies make camera bags to fit this configuration properly.

I am looking for a bag that will fit and weather protect my camera and lens (and nothing else).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try one of the Crumpler [Jimmy Bo](http://www.crumpler.co.uk/?product=Jimmy_Bo&page=details&product_id=JBO700-005&view=8&size=&lsc=&lcc=)'s, they come in various sizes.

Or even the [4 million dollar home](http://www.crumpler.com/AU/Camera-Bags/Camera-Bags/4-Million-Dollar-Home.html?LanguageCode=EN&SKU=MDH001-B00P40).

Comment: I went with the 4 million dollar home .. very happy with crumpler

Answer (score 1):

I just got the  Think tank speed demon. Think it should fit the 5d. (it is not a bag but a belt system which I find easier to use)

http://www.thinktankphoto.com/products/speed-demon-belt-pack.aspx

It is available for less on Adorama.

Comment: nice, this bag looks like it will probably fit my need

Comment: Glad it helped. I hear that many pro-photographers here use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Caselogic SLRC-200 SLR Camera Holster](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002DW96M6), I have the [Caselogic SLRC-201](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001TZUS98) just a little bit longer. I think these bags have very good protection for your camera. The 201 has an suspension so that the lens cannot touch the bottom of the bag.

Comment: I think this has trouble fitting the 7d which is of similar size afaik

Answer (score 0):

I like my LowePro OffTrail 2 for such things (though the OffTrail 1 might be large enough for you).

http://products.lowepro.com/product/Off-Trail-2,1981,7.htm

Small, easy to carry as either a shoulderbag or a beltpack, removable side pouches for extra gear, sturdy.